# WooCommerce | Custom order_id PRIOR pushing to the WC database

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I'd need to set up the logic for order_id prior it's being pushed to the DB. I've got custom page generating unique ID via Javascript before the order is even created. This ID is being transmitted through the pages towards checkout page where it's getting :

```
<script>ID = sessionStorage.getItem('orderID');document.write(ID)</script>
```

Under the checkout page, I need to take that value and once the order is created need to push such value to DB instead of default value, which is being incremented by each other order.

I know that I can make a filter in functions.php of theme settings to change it in UI but the the issue here is that I need to have such order ID same as the unique ID created with JS also in DB.

I believe that CRUD methods exists and are possible to do such job within wp_insert_post() and 'woocommerce_new_order_data' filter but I do not really know how to implement this rule to existing wc-order-data-store-cpt.php file to replace WooCommerce generated and incremented order_id with my custom order_id.

Comment: I don't get how this is any different than what you already asked yesterday. Using the appropriate hook, _is_ the way to go.

Comment: Yes, but the hook for #add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' ); is used after the order creation in DB. I need to set it up to use specific order_id inserted even into the mysql db of woocommerce.

Comment: Then I'd go check what other filters might be executed during the order creation process. It _might_ be that what you want is not actually possible though, without modifying WooCommerce source code directly - the ID field in the database is numeric, as far as I know - so if anyone was able to manipulate the ID before insertion, with alphanumeric prefixes like in the example from the other thread, then that would crash. So the developers simply might not have made that possible to begin with, deliberately.

Comment: I'm trying to set only numeric nr. instead the woocommerce where it generate for e.g. 14301 I wanna set same nr. of digits like e.g. 38501. I saw that the method woocommerce_new_order_data should be for that available but not sure if it could change even order_id... In the Abstract_WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT create() method, woocommerce_new_order_data filter hook allow you to filter the data inside the function wp_insert_post() before it's saved on creation.

In the WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT create() method, woocommerce_new_order action hook allow you to trigger some code on order creation.